# Worker Nodes showing up as NotReady after upgrade to latest K8 version

Tags: kubernetes

Worker nodes upgraded to latest k8s version and I am facing the 'NotReady' status of those worker nodes. I see 'PIDPressure - False' when I do a 'kubectl describe' for these nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> PIDPressure - False

^^ is an expected condition of the healthy node, it means that kubelet has sufficient PIDs available for normal operation.

Need more details:

- Kubelet version? `kubectl version`
- Can you share a full output of the describe command? `kubectl describe node <node-name>`
- ssh to the node and run `sudo journalctl -u kubelet --all|tail`

Comment: Actually, In my case, I found that these runners had some k8s containers running in stale state. After terminating those and reinstalling the latest K8s, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the stale Docker containers on the K8s nodes and restarting the services has resolved my issue. Upgrading to latest K8s is not necessary.